# CSS keyframes animation not working on safari browsers

Tags: css, reactjs, safari, webkit, css-animations

```css
.css3-logo {
  -webkit-animation-name: techs-animation1;
  animation-name: techs-animation1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 9s;
  animation-duration: 9s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes techs-animation1 {
  0% {
    color: #000000;
  }
  5.56% {
    color: #ff0000;
  }
  11.11% {
    color: #000000;
  }
  100% {
    color: #000000;
  }
}

@keyframes techs-animation1 {
  0% {
    color: #000000;
  }
  5.56% {
    color: #ff0000;
  }
  11.11% {
    color: #000000;
  }
  100% {
    color: #000000;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="tech-logo css3-logo" title="CSS3">Hello</h1>
```

I am trying to build a color-change `animation` in my react.js app.  It works correctly on Chrome and Firefox, but not on Safari (version 16.4.1 app on iPhone):

```css
.css3-logo {
  -webkit-animation-name: techs-animation1;
  animation-name: techs-animation1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 9s;
  animation-duration: 9s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes techs-animation1 {
  0% {
    color: var(--black);
  }
  5.56% {
    color: var(--css3);
  }
  11.11% {
    color: var(--black);
  }
  100% {
    color: var(--black);
  }
}

@keyframes techs-animation1 {
  0% {
    color: var(--black);
  }
  5.56% {
    color: var(--css3);
  }
  11.11% {
    color: var(--black);
  }
  100% {
    color: var(--black);
  }
}
```

I've tried so many different variations and formats and nothing works.  I currently have all the commands separated onto different lines (as opposed to combining them like:  `-webkit-animation: techs-animation1 9s infinite;`).

This is one of a dozen similar animations for other logos that all are supposed to change color in sequential order over the course of the 9s animation.  Again, works correctly on Chrome and Firefox.

All online and StackOverflow searches indicate that Safari uses @-webkit-keyframes, that they should be placed before the @keyframes animations, and that 0% and 100% need to be defined.  But this still doesn't work.

This is a react.js app, and the color change animation is supposed to work on a react-icon I'm importing, in case that has some impact on Safari:

```js
<DiCss3 className="tech-logo css3-logo" title="CSS3" />
```

Comment: What version of Safari are you using, please?

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I am looking at the app on an iphone with ios version 16.4.1, so this is the current version of Safari and the animation is not working.

Comment: Dude, please provide the minimum code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I appreciate the advice.  I am new to this space.  I added a code snippet to mimic the effect.  In my app I am importing and using a react-icons icon (DiCss3), but I couldn't figure out how to do that in the code snippet, so I just replaced the imported icon with a standard <h1> element and applied the animation.

Comment: Here is the application:
https://github.com/ekirbs/portfolio-v5
The animation is located in the techs component.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was able to cure it by wrapping the object that had animation on it in a div and moving the animation on to the div, no webkits required.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34821053)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).